# Invalid API key

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Какой API выбрать? Ошибка почему то.(Yandex Maps JS API): Invalid API key [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
//Дождёмся загрузки API и готовности DOM.
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {

  var result = document.getElementById('result'),
    myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
      center: [56.294008726996786,39.376220410095236], // Москва
      zoom: 16
    });

  // все ок
  result.textContent = 'map init';

  // куда скакать
  function clickGoto() {

    // город
    var city = this.getAttribute('data-goto'); // или this.getAttribute('title')
    result.textContent = city;

    // получение координат по адресу - асинхронная функция
    var myGeocoder = ymaps.geocode(city);
    myGeocoder.then(
      function(res) {
        coords = res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates();

        // переходим по координатам
        myMap.panTo(coords, {
          flying: 1
        });
        // добавляем маркер
        var placeMark = new ymaps.Placemark(coords, {
          balloonContent: city
        });
        myMap.geoObjects.add(placeMark);
      },
      function(err) {
        alert('Ошибка');
      }
    );
    return false;
  }

  // навешиваем обработчики
  var col = document.getElementsByClassName('goto');
  for (var i = 0, n = col.length; i < n; ++i) {
    col[i].onclick = clickGoto;
    result.textContent = result.textContent + ' ' + i;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1.72/?apikey=8090ae01-4b01-4133-849e-863fdf4b95d3&lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>

<a href="#" class="goto" data-goto="Кольчугино, Центр, Володарского, " title="Карта объекта">Показать на карте</a>
<div class="iframe_bl">
<div style="display:none;" id="result"></div>
<div id="map" style="height: 350px; margin:0 auto;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Зачем вы указываете его дважды и зачем там `<>`?

Comment: По инструкции так

Answer (score 2):

Подключайте API правильно и всё будет работать.

```
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=eef841e5-c60b-4c91-a933-d22090ea8fa7&lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

В инструкции в `<угловых скобках>` указано что в этом месте надо написать. Без угловых скобок.

Соответственно `apikey=<ваш API-ключ>` надо заменять на `apikey=eef8...a7`, а не `apikey=<eef8...a7>`. А `lang=<идентификатор языка>` на `lang=ru_RU`

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
cancel.png:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
api-maps.yandex.ru/:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: @AlexSpector777 вчера всё работало. Возможно какой-то баг на стороне Яндекса

Comment: врядли, в инструкции есть <>. С ними пишет (Yandex Maps JS API): Invalid API key

Comment: М-дя, а lang вы тоже в <> запихали? В инструкции тоже есть

Answer (score 0):

Invalid API key - ошибка может быть вызвана неправильным ключом или блокировкой на стороне Яндекса, например, при нарушении условий использования или превышении лимитов.

Если вы уверены, что ключ правильный и лимитов вы не превышали, обратитесь в саппорт.